# ImportError: cannot import name 'users'

Tags: python, django

I am new to python , I am building djangorestframework API following below tutorial
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/
I have configured
Python 3.5
PIP 9.0.1
Django 2.0

tutorial/tutorial/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import users
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^users/', user.site.urls),    
]
```

Error :

File "/home/pradeep/tutorial/tutorial/tutorial/urls.py", line 18, in 
    from django.contrib import users
ImportError: cannot import name 'users'

Comment: I can't find a line `from django.contrib import users` on the linked tutorial page. Is it on another page?

Comment: Did you try to import from this submodule ? `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
from django.contrib import users
```

To:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```